# How can i check if the file extension is uppercase or lowercase?

Tags: c#

I have this line in my code:

```
if (address.EndsWith("GIF") || (address.EndsWith("BMP") || address.EndsWith("JPEG") || address.EndsWith("TIFF") || address.EndsWith("RAW") || address.EndsWith("PNG")))
```

And for example now the website address in the address variable is: www.test.jpg
Then it will never get in the IF and jump out/continue.

I want it to be in all the extensions uppercase and lowercase for example "GIF" and "gif"
How can i do it ?

( sub question If i want to check for file extension doing EndsWith("gif" is enough or i have to add a dot before it like".gif" or like ".jpeg" ? )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unlike the other answers so far, I'd probably stick with `EndsWith` but switch to the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131430.aspx) that accepts a [`StringComparison`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) parameter, e.g.:

```
address.EndsWith("GIF",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

You should generally *avoid* using `ToLower` or `ToUpper` just to be able to perform a comparison, because most string comparison facilities in the framework offer some form of option that allows you to perform the comparison whilst ignoring case.

Comment: Nice, forgot about this

Answer (score 3):

you simply don't need to

```
 address.ToLower().EndsWith("gif")
```

if you really need to

```
 bool lowercase = address.ToLower() == address
```

---

You could clean up your code too - I believe you should incorporate Damien's answer into this but didn't want to take credit away from where it is due.

```
var extensions = new string[]{"gif","jpg","something"};
if(extensions.Any(x => address.ToLower().EndsWith(x)))
```

Comment: The first == needs to be a =

Comment: @misha - Cheers, early morning!

Answer (score 3):

For lower case you should just convert to lower and then match the ending.

do it like this

```
string temp = address.ToLower(); 
if (temp .EndsWith(".gif") || (temp .EndsWith(".bmp") || temp .EndsWith(".jpeg") || temp .EndsWith(".tiff") || temp .EndsWith(".raw") || temp .EndsWith(".png")))
```

**for your subquestion**,

you need to add `.` in the extension. Because otherwise your address www.testgif will be considered as a valid address.

Comment: No One in your example all the extensions for example ".gif" already lowcase and temp is lowcase too what will happen in this case if for example the address end with ".GIF" uppercase ?

Comment: i have first converted the address to lower. the check will not bypass it. as GIF will be first converted to gif and then matched. and incase you want to use address in futurei have created a copy to temp before using it.

Answer (score 1):

Get extension using [`Path.GetExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx) method.

> Returns the extension of the specified path string.

```
string ext = Path.GetExtension(address);
```

Then check all char in extension is uppercase or not.

```
public static bool IsAllCharLowerCase(string ext)
{
    foreach(char c in ext)
    {
         if (char.IsUpper(c))
         {
             return false;
         }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Regarding your check - shouldn't it be true only if ALL characters are lower case?

Answer (score 0):

Just change all extensions to upper case before evaluating them, like so

```
address.ToUpper().EndsWith("GIF") etc.
```

Checking with the dot e.g. ".GIF" will give you more surety that it actually is an extension and not an extension less file ending in GIF for example.